# How to received alert() action from javascript into Cocoa application via WebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webview

I was develop some Cocoa application with `WebView`. Now I can evaluate javascript to HTML file by using `evaluateWebScript:`

But I need to receive an `alert()` event from javascript to display in Cocoa's `NSAlertSheet`.

How to do with cocoa development ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set an object as the `WebUIDelegate` of the `WebView` (using the `setUIDelegate:` method) and in that object implement the `‑webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:` delegate method. This method will be called when a page loaded into the `WebView` calls the `alert()` JavaScript function.

In your implementation of the delegate method, you should display an alert. The alert should:

1. display the exact message string that is passed in to the method
2. indicate that the message comes from JavaScript
3. contain only one button, an **OK** button

Here is a basic example:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    NSAlert* jsAlert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"JavaScript"
                                       defaultButton:@"OK" 
                                     alternateButton:nil 
                                         otherButton:nil 
                           informativeTextWithFormat:@"%@", message];
    [jsAlert beginSheetModalForWindow:sender.window modalDelegate:nil didEndSelector:NULL contextInfo:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [override](http://slayeroffice.com/code/custom_alert/) JavaScript `alert` function on `window`. In your custom `alert` you can redirect to predefined url, e.g. `app://alert/something%32is%32wrong`. That kind of redirect can be handled by `UIWebView` through `webView:shouldLoadRequest:`.

PS: I didn't try it :)

Comment: This question is tagged `cocoa` which means it's Mac OS X not iOS.